# Firing off event when selecting first option of select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, window

My usage is simple, I have a simple `select` element on my page.

```
<select id="project-dropdown">
    <option data-url="/constructions/6">Test 1</option>
    <option data-url="/constructions/7">Test 2</option>
</select>
```

And in Javascript:

```
$('#project-dropdown').change(function() {
    var url = $(this).find(':selected').data('url');
    window.location = url;
});
```

This event works fine except when I want to go to the first option. The page starts out with the first element selected so I can't fire the `changed` event on it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try $('#project-dropdown').load(function() {
    var url = $(this).find(':selected').data('url');
    window.location = url;
});

Comment: How do you expect the user to know how to select the first one? Maybe consider a "please select" placeholder or a button to "go".

Comment: Either add a placeholder as default option or just trigger change event like this: http://jsfiddle.net/skYEC/

Comment: If you don't want the `window.location` to change if they select the option that's the same as the current url, then why not just get the current url path from window.location.href; see if it's the same as the data-url, and then skip the window.location = url.

Comment: @stevemarvell: You're 100% correct. I need to get up and stretch my legs, brain is giving out late in the afternoon. :)

Comment: The key is the `size` attribute of the `select` element.  By default, `size` is set to 1, which results in the *currently selected option* displayed on a single line, which in this case is the first option by default.  If you set `<select ... size=2>` in this example, you get a two-line listbox, and neither option is selected by default, so the user can choose either one (from *Javascript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition*, p. 986).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a little hack like this works for you?

HTML Part:

```
<select id="project-dropdown">
    <option data-url="#">Select a value</option>
    <option data-url="/constructions/6">Test 1</option>
    <option data-url="/constructions/7">Test 2</option>
</select>
```

JS Part:

```
$('#project-dropdown').change(function() {
     var url = $(this).find(':selected').data('url');

    if(url !== "#")
         window.location = url;
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4UhQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Just call *$('#project-dropdown').change();* after change binding. Like this:

```
$('#project-dropdown').change(function() {
    var url = $(this).find(':selected').data('url');
    window.location = url;
});

$('#project-dropdown').change();
```

[Here is its JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmertayak/92gb6/).

Comment: For me, this JSFiddle shows *nothing* in its output panel (Windows 64 Pro with FF 57.0 (64-bit) and Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you change your HTML to:

```
<select id="project-dropdown" size=2>
    <option data-url="/constructions/6">Test 1</option>
    <option data-url="/constructions/7">Test 2</option>
</select>
```

By setting `size=2` you override the default value of `1`, which causes the list to be displayed as a single line, with the initial option pre-selected (with the side-effect that clicking it does not trigger a `change` event).

Setting size to 2 or more causes the options to be displayed in a list that is `size` lines high, with no initial selections, so that the user can choose any of the options, including the first.